# Using moq on a complex class reference

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oop, moq

I had this in the `[TestInitialize]`

```
var classHelper = new classHelper(mockSessionRepository.Object, new SecurityTokenAgent(), AuthorityReporting.Instance, new UserClientProcessor());

locationRepo = new LocationRepo(mockXmlReader.Object, classHelper);
```

and I thought to moq the `classHelper` I would do :

```
mockClassHelper = new Mock<IClassHelper>(mockSessionRepository.Object, new SecurityTokenAgent(), AuthorityReporting.Instance, new UserClientProcessor());

locationRepo = new LocationRepo(mockXmlReader.Object, mockSecurityHelper.Object);
```

This seems logical, it just also seems to break all my `[TestMethods]`.
Please enlighten me, on if this is logical ?

EDIT : The Location Repo ctor

```
internal LocationRepo(IXmlReader xmlReader, IClassHelper classHelper)
{
    this.xmlReader = xmlReader;
    this.classHelper = classHelper;
    this.Init();
}

/// <summary>
/// Prevents a default instance of the <see cref="LocationRepo" /> class from being created.
/// </summary>
private LocationRepo() : this(new XmlReader(), new ClassHelper()){ }
```

Answer (score 3):

An *Interface* doesnt have a constructor, so you dont need to pass parameters to it, so to create a **mock** to `IClassHelper` just do it:

```
var mockClassHelper = new Mock<IClassHelper>();
```

And it is the wonderful world of the use of interfaces.

Comment: I did try that ( actually first ) why would that still break the test ?

Comment: @Iiolioa Show the code of the ````LocationRepo```` ctor